# Makefile optimisation of multiple targets

Tags: c++, c, compilation, makefile

So as part of a few tools I'm making in C++, I wanted to be able to test each tool individually. There are multiple tools with multiple testing files, and hence I want multiple executables as my end result. I was hoping the magic of Makefiles could make my life much easier.

This is my current Makefile template:

```
# Compilation
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -pedantic -Wall -c # -g -Wextra

all: lbLog lbString

lbLog:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) 'src/lbLog.cpp' -o lbLog.o
    $(CXX) 'examples/lbLog_example.cpp' lbLog.o -o 'tests/lbLog_example'
    rm lbLog.o

lbString:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) 'src/lbString.cpp' -o lbString.o
    $(CXX) 'examples/lbString_example.cpp' lbString.o -o 'tests/lbString_example'
    rm lbString.o
```

Intended file structure is

- driver example files are in '/examples' (.cpp)
- sources/tools (.cpp) are in '/src'
- headers in '/include'
- output exe's in '/tests'

So the question is, is there anyway to optimise the makefile, so I can virtually 'set and forget'? I don't want to have to add every new tool to the Makefile hopefully. Because it's such a repeating pattern, that there must be a way to smarten it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a proper makefile at all. It doesn't specify any prerequisite/target pairs that make can take advantage of.

To take advantage of what make does for you you want something more like this:

```
# Compilation
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -pedantic -Wall -c # -g -Wextra

all: tests/lbLog_example tests/lbString_example

lbLog.o: src/lbLog.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@    

tests/lbLog_example: examples/lbLog_example.cpp lbLog.o
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@

lbString.o: src/lbString.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

tests/lbString_example: examples/lbString_example.cpp lbString.o
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@
```

Which tells make to build the test executables by default and that the test executables depend on the toplevel object files and how to build the object files from their respective sources. And now make knows that it needs to rebuild the target files when their prerequisite files change but not otherwise (as opposed to your original which always recompiles everything).

You could even clean that up some more with [pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro) like this:

```
# Compilation
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -pedantic -Wall -c # -g -Wextra

all: tests/lbLog_example tests/lbString_example

lb%.o: src/lb%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

tests/lb%_example: examples/lb%_example.cpp lb%.o
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@
```

If you allowed for building the object files in the `src` directory you could remove the `lb%.o: src/lb%.cpp` rule entirely as well. Build the test executables in the `examples` directory and I believe you could remove the `$(CXX) $^ -o $@` body from the `tests/lb%_example: examples/lb%_example.cpp lb%.o` target as well which would end up with this (untested) makefile I believe:

```
# Compilation
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -pedantic -Wall -c # -g -Wextra

all: tests/lbLog_example tests/lbString_example

tests/lb%_example: examples/lb%_example.cpp lb%.o
```

This last bit works (assuming I got it all right) because make comes with many [built-in rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) for common build patterns.

Comment: I see the difference between my 'makefile' and the real thing. That makes more sense, thanks. But I was wondering, in the second example you have, what in it makes it remove the object files?

Comment: make has special rules for handling what it calls "intermediate files". If file `X` lists file `Y` as a prereq and file `Y` has source file `Z` as a prereq then make knows that it can build `Y` when it needs to and knows that `Y` won't change if `Z` doesn't so it deletes `Y` when it is done with it. See [Chains of Implicit Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules) for more details about this. (Assuming you meant why do you see make "run" `rm lbString.o lbLog.` at the end of the output. It isn't really running that by the way that's just telling you what it did.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can identify a rule to generate tools from the sources, take a look at these make functions:

- patsubst
- wildcard

Comment: This is, at best, part of an answer.